# Export db table to excel using php to a different directory

Tags: php, csv, export-to-excel

my code works successfully . but i dont know how to save the .csv file to a seperate directory D:\xampp\htdocs\works_try\export_files.  and my file resides in D:\xampp\htdocs\works_try\master\file.php my code given below .

```
<?php
$server='localhost';
$login='root';
$password='';
$db='tc';
$filename='export1.csv';
$conn=mysqli_connect($server, $login, $password,$db);
$fp = fopen('export_files/../'.$filename, "w");
$sql="SELECT * FROM student";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$line = "";
$comma = "";
foreach($row as $name => $value) {
$line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
$comma = ",";
}
$line .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $line);
mysqli_data_seek($res, 0);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

$line = "";
$comma = "";
foreach($row as $value) {
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
    $comma = ",";
}
$line .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $line);
}
fclose($fp);
echo " success :)  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   Please check the file ";
?>
```

i should save the .csv file in folder_name export_files and my php code runs in the folder_name master.my problem is csv file getting saved in folder_name master itself.where file should save in export_files.

Comment: Can you edit the question so that proper directory structure would be known?

Comment: @Sagar Guhe : edited now check

Comment: I think this should work `fopen('../export_files/'.$filename, "w");` let me know if this works

Comment: @Sagar Guhe :working thanks :)

Comment: I am Glad it worked!! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use fopen($filename, "w") then file will be save inside the folder. if you want to save the file present outside folder ie(export_files is separate folder and file present in seperate folder ) then try this

```
fopen('../export_files/'.$filename, "w");
```

the file will be saved inside export_files folder

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in the root folder of the site use this:

```
$filename='export1.csv';
$conn=mysqli_connect($server, $login, $password,$db);
$fp = fopen('./'.$filename, "w");
```

Comment: :it is not working . file getting saved in the same folder

Comment: :export_files is different folder and master is another folder. i should save the csv file outside not inside. so the dir are master/file.php. and export_files is a separate folder

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the following code then the path will be in relation to the directory of the running script. e.g. as example going one directory up and in export_files.

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE__) .'/../export_files/export1.csv';
```

you can also use other constants like `__DIR__` see http://php.net/manual/de/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: :export_files is different folder and master is another folder. i should save the csv file outside not inside. so the dir are master/file.php. and export_files is a separate folder

Comment: that is exactly what i have thought, your running script is in some dir (master) which is gotten by dirname(__FILE__)  from there go one directory up with ".." and into the directory "export_files".